# Building an Augmented Reality Piano

Tags: android, iphone-app

I would like to build an App similar to this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHJ_I6DmFNw

I have built a working prototype using the Vuforia SDK and Virtual Buttons, however I cannot make the piano work with several buttons (e.g Chords) at the same time since my camera is placed right above the piano and the user´s hand hides buttons that are not intended to be played. The the app detects the absence of tracking of the button and plays the notes that should not be played.

On the video the camera is placed in front of the piano. I tried this but I can´t make my app detect the image target in this position. So I think Vuforia might not be the right AR tool for this.

Is there anyone that can suggest me and good AR tool to be able to track the piano and the fingers of the user?